# Deploying a Next.js Application Without Node.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js, webserver

Can a Next.js application be configured or built so all the routes are handled client-side and any server files are static? I want to deploy the application as a static website without the need for Node.js.

Comment: I'd recommend a read through [Next.js Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).

Comment: The exported files contain hrefs relative to the sever root ("/static/..."), so the links are broken. How can I configure the application so it works if deployed to a directory under the server root (i.e. http://server/app)? The exported files are optimized where all the extra whitespace is stripped out. Is there a config option to retain the whitespace?